# Restoring old workspace switcher

Tags: unity, 11.10, workspaces

Previously (11.04) when I Ctrl+Alt+Arrow Keyed I'd get a 2x2 grid of workspaces to switch to which I could do really easily. Since I updated however this has become one single row.

I've tried installing Workspace Indicator and others but no matter how many rows I set, I always just get one.

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you using ubuntu2d desktop?

Comment: That's the one I'm choosing on login

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for anyone else, this seems to have been fixed now after using `sudo apt-get upgrade`

Answer (score 2):

This is a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/715587) with ubuntu2d apparently.

There is a python script used by [one of the users on that bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-2d/+bug/715587/comments/9) that might work for you.

Add your issue to that bug report to push developers to solve it ;)

Answer (score 0):

CCSM, General Options (or Settings -I don't know, my UBUNTU is in Spanish-), and choose 2 frames? vertical and 2 horizontal.